# Gracefully stopping an Akka Stream

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Given's akka doc I would expect the stream to stop after 7th/8th element. Why is it not stopping ? It continues all the way to the last element (20th).

What I want to achive is that on system terminate, the stream stops requesting new elements and the system to wait termination until all elements in the stream are fully processed (reach the sink)

```scala
object StreamKillSwitch extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem(Behaviors.ignore, "sks")
  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = system.executionContext

  val (killStream, done) =
    Source(1 to 20)
      .viaMat(KillSwitches.single)(Keep.right)
      .map(i => {
        system.log.info(s"Start task $i")
        Thread.sleep(100)
        system.log.info(s"End task $i")
        i
      })
      .toMat(Sink.foreach(println))(Keep.both)
      .run()

  CoordinatedShutdown(system)
    .addTask(CoordinatedShutdown.PhaseServiceUnbind, "stop-receiving") {
      () => Future(killStream.shutdown()).map(_ => Done)
    }

  CoordinatedShutdown(system)
    .addTask(CoordinatedShutdown.PhaseServiceRequestsDone, "wait-processing-complete") {
      () => done
    }

  Thread.sleep(720)

  system.terminate()
  Await.ready(system.whenTerminated, 5.seconds)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to "fix" the problem but I'm struggling to explain the behaviour.

For some reason, your implementation of the `map` (specifically `Thread.sleep`) is causing the future/promise callbacks in `killStream.shutdown()` to not propagate fast enough. My guess is that it fills up the main dispatcher with blocked threads.

You may increase the amount of source elements `Source(1 to 10000)` and the `Await` timeout to see that the kill switch eventually propagates.

However, adding async boundaries does solve the problem and has the expected results.

Replace your `map` with following `mapAsync` and it works as expected.

```scala
.mapAsync(1) { i =>
  Future {
    system.log.info(s"Start task $i")
    Thread.sleep(100)
    system.log.info(s"Start task $i")
    i
  }
}
```

Similar result can be achieved by addition of `async` marker.

```scala
.map(i => {
  system.log.info(s"Start task $i")
  Thread.sleep(100)
  system.log.info(s"End task $i")
  i
})
.async
```

Comment: I'm not sure is the Thread.sleep.
 Just .map { i =>   system.log.info(s"Start task $i") } still does not stop, and continues to log all elements.
MapAsync does indeed fix it

Comment: Did you report the bug ? if not i can do it

Comment: @AdrianS  `Thread.sleep` removal helps but you need to increase the amount of element to process from 20 to something much bigger to allow termination to finish.

Comment: @AdrianS I'm not sure if it's a bug. I think this is how akka is designed. You should not block the main dispatcher with IO or Thread.sleep

Comment: @AdrianS but it'd be great to see the akka devs reaction, could you please create an issue on github?

Comment: opened a question on Lightbend forum https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/bug-or-by-design-behavior-stoping-a-stream-via-killswitch-map-combination/7548

Comment: Hi. I was testing it as well. I managed to stop your stream only using `system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(3 seconds) { killSwitch.shutdown() }` using only `map` without `async` or `mapAsync`. But not with `CoordinatedShutdown`. The problem is the `CoordinatedShutdown` which I think is designed for Actors, not stream...

Comment: @Felipe afaik, streams run on top of actors

Comment: yes. you are right. the whole stream runs on top of one Actor to ensure thread-safe. I think this is why you cannot stop using `CoordinatedShutdown` unless you use async boundaries. With `async` or `mapAsync` you run each operator in a different actor. Then `CoordinatedShutdown` is not blocked.